# Sizing a capacitor for MCU's Vs to withstand cold cranking amps of an engine

Tags: capacitor, batteries

I have a microcontroller whose power supply is wired into a car's battery at about 14.6V.  I noticed that whenever the car cranks the microcontroller's voltage supply at 3.3V dips significantly and the MCU enters a stalled/frozen state.  It has to be reset to perform its normal tasks.

To combat this I added a voltage supervisor that monitors the 3.3V supply line and if the voltage dips below 3.08V it will wait until the voltage rises above this threshold and pulse a reset signal to my microcontroller's EN.  This is okay but not a perfect solution, because when I reboot the MCU I lose data and need about 15s for the MCU to run through its setup etc.

So I'd like to prevent the under voltage in the first place.  I have a capacitor directly after a fuse and diode on the 14.6V line that is about 100uF.  How large would this capacitor need to be to prevent voltage dropouts from cold cranking amps (CCA)?  Assuming my PCB is consuming 0.5A at 3.3V?  From what I read it seems this voltage dip could last from 1-20s. This is a typical lead acid automotive battery.[image: graph]

Comment: this is an XY question ... you are asking about your solution to a problem ... please ask about the problem itself

Comment: Something is wrong with your 3.3v supply. How is that 3.3v being generated?  Variation between 10-15v should not matter unless something is very poorly designed for your application.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm guessing that the sharp falling edge of the voltage is more of a problem than the lower voltage. A regulator with poor dynamic response to line regulation changes will not respond quickly enough and this falling edge will transfer to the output.

You could use a better regulator, or you can try to smooth the input voltage.

Adding a cap in parallel with the battery won't help, the starter will quickly discharge it. But, if you add a diode, then the cap should help smooth the voltage enough to make it easier for the regulator.

For the cap to supply all the power for even one second, it would need to be enormous. But, you don't need to supply all the power, you only need to smooth it out.

C = I * delta_T / delta_V

To keep the math simple, assume that voltage and current are constant, not exactly true, but good enough for a first order calculation.

Assuming a buck regulator, the regulator input current will be about 1/3 of 0.5 A, or 0.17 A.

delta_V is about 14 - 10 = 4V

How fast the voltage can change without upsetting the regulator is a guess, maybe 4V in 50 mS.

C = 0.17A * 0.05s / 4V = 2100 uF

This calculation is more of a feasibility study than a rigorous calculation. I would start smaller than this, then increase the capacitance until it works reliably, then double it for margin.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbcP6o.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Note that the capacitance required, depends on the slope of current draw.  An LDO will have a constant-current characteristic, as above. An SMPS will have an inverse curve. Both can be calculated handily on my website here: https://seventransistorlabs.com/Calc/PSHoldUp.html [Edited by a moderator.]

Comment: @TimWilliams - For your constant power calculator, there seems to be redundant input information. If I know the first 3, the 4th is redundant. How do I know which input data it is using?

Comment: It's always using the 4th; the first 3 are convenience to calculate it, or you can enter it manually (in which case the first 3 will be out of sync with that value).

Comment: There are several issues with the proposed schematic, including risk of blowing the fuse or D1 on abrupt voltage changes, and the capacitor on transcient overvoltage as occur in [load dump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_dump). Designing an automotive power supply is hard.

Answer (score 11):

If you have recorded the battery voltage on an oscilloscope and it only dips to 10V, then the problem isn’t with the capacity per se. The buck regulator somehow doesn’t work – it’s way too sluggish. Such dips should not matter in a regulator that works properly.

Comment: We use to design for 6V cold crank for 30 seconds. A SEPIC converter would work good but where in the electrical system and in the vehicle is this located. What are the temperature requirements, is there load dump protection, how about double reverse battery jump just to name a few other things you need to consider.

Comment: @Gil Yup, all this. I've designed front ends for small modules covering exactly all these ratings; SEPIC does indeed work well, and a couple of other tricks covers the rest (most interesting I guess being the MOV + depletion MOS voltage limiter to handle load dump and transients). All depends how complete the scope is.

Comment: It definitely looks like the control system for the buck regulator is poorly designed for this use case. I would start looking there.

Comment: One trick used for load dump in the late 90's was use a diode from Motorola designed for this and then down size the wire so it would adsorb the transient. That was a bit tricky with the harness manufacturer but they got it. Similar to the trick with headlamps to cut the voltage so they would last.